# Editing source of a file via name with my extension

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I am writing a VSC extension.  What I wanna do is be able to edit a file by using the name of said file to find it?

I just don't know how I would edit the source of said file.  I also don't know how to find that file.

EX:

I pass in a name to a function that finds and returns the file needed to edit.

```
function -> (name: string) -> File

function -> ("script.py") -> ./src/script.py
```

I hope this makes sense???

Comment: `vscode.workspace.findFiles`

Answer (score 0):

Do you not know the filePath?

```js
    // note escaped backslashes below
    const file = await vscode.workspace.openTextDocument("C:\\Users\\Mark\\jump-and-select\\command-alias\\jsconfig.json");
    // or use showTextDocument() instead if you want to open and see the document and changes
    console.log(file);

    // file.getText() has all your file text
    // then look at edit(callback: (editBuilder: TextEditorEdit) => functionality
```